# aggregating columns based on commas

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregation, analysis

I have the following dataframe and I'm trying to separate the commas and turn that particular name(s) into their own individual columns and specify if that particular column names exist (which are separated by commas) for that particular ID. (1 = Yes, 0 = No) Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
ID<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Details<- c("V1,V2", "V1,V3", "V1", "V2", "V3,V4", "V2,V3" )

data.frame <- data.frame(ID, Details, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
V1<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0)
V2<-c(1,0,0,1,0,1)
V3<-c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
V4<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0)

data.frame1<-data.frame(ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way I see is to would be to build a data.frame for each of these vectors hidden in strings and bind them. `purrr` can help to make it quite compact. Note that column `ID` isn't needed, I'll work on `Details` directly.

```
library(purrr)
df <- map_dfr(strsplit(Details, ","),
              ~data.frame(t(setNames(rep(1, length(.x)), .x))))
df[is.na(df)] <- 0

#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  1  0  0
# 2  1  0  1  0
# 3  1  0  0  0
# 4  0  1  0  0
# 5  0  0  1  1
# 6  0  1  1  0
```

You could also split and unlist to get distinct values, and then look them up in the original vector:

```
unique_v <- unique(unlist(strsplit(Details, ",")))
map_dfc(unique_v, ~as.numeric(grepl(.x, Details)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#      V1    V2    V3    V4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0     0
# 2     1     0     1     0
# 3     1     0     0     0
# 4     0     1     0     0
# 5     0     0     1     1
# 6     0     1     1     0
```

We could do some dirty string evaluation also if you know the number of columns:

```
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,ncol=4,nrow=6))
eval(parse(text=paste0("m[",ID,", c(",gsub("V","",Details),")] <- 1")))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  1  0  0
# 2  1  0  1  0
# 3  1  0  0  0
# 4  0  1  0  0
# 5  0  0  1  1
# 6  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using the `tidyverse` package. `dat` is your example data frame. `dat2` is the final data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  separate_rows(Details) %>%
  mutate(Value = 1L) %>%
  spread(Details, Value, fill = 0L)
dat2
#   ID V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  1  1  0  0
# 2  2  1  0  1  0
# 3  3  1  0  0  0
# 4  4  0  1  0  0
# 5  5  0  0  1  1
# 6  6  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

One option with `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind.data.frame(ID, # or data.frame$ID
                 mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(data.frame$Details), ",")))
# output
  ID V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  1  1  0  0
2  2  1  0  1  0
3  3  1  0  0  0
4  4  0  1  0  0
5  5  0  0  1  1
6  6  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution. I have renamed your data.frames `data1` and `data2`.

```
data1 <- data.frame(ID, Details, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data2 <- data.frame(ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)        

nms <- unique(unlist(strsplit(data1$Details, ",")))
data3 <- cbind.data.frame(ID, sapply(nms, grepl, data1$Details))
data3[-1] <- lapply(data3[-1], as.integer)
```

Now compare `data3` with your expected result `data2`.

```
all.equal(data2, data3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Note, however, that

```
identical(data2, data3)
#[1] FALSE
```

This is because I have used `as.integer` and the values in `data2` are of class `"numeric"`. If this makes a difference, you can change the `lapply` instruction above to use `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

using base R:

```
 xtabs(val~.,cbind.data.frame(ID=rep(ID,lengths(s<-strsplit(Details,","))),Details=unlist(s),val=1))
   Details
ID  V1 V2 V3 V4
  1  1  1  0  0
  2  1  0  1  0
  3  1  0  0  0
  4  0  1  0  0
  5  0  0  1  1
  6  0  1  1  0
```